# laravel validation callback not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to use callback to simply to check my form input, the offical code is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

the following is my function

```
public function addthread(Request $request) {


    $input = $request->all();
    $rules = array('title' => 'required|unique:thread|max:255');
    $message = array('title.required' => 'The :attribute field is aaa required.');
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $message);

    $validator->after(function($validator) {
        if ($this->checkOpt()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('num_opt', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
            echo 'test';        
        }
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('addthreadhtml')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

}

public function checkOpt() {
    return false;
}
```

the blade tpl:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="container" stytle="max-width:80%">  
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  
@endif
```

The num_opt error never print out, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkOpt() is returning FALSE, so the code will never enter the if statment.

```
if ($this->checkOpt()) { // this is returning false, right ?? so, its not adding the error
        $validator->errors()->add('num_opt', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
        echo 'test';        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your checkOpt() always returns false, so your condition won't ever be satisfied.